# How to get get page source in codeception yii 2

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, functional-testing, codeception

I need save the source code of failed test to fix it. How to get the source html while using codeception test in yii 2?

I cannot get `$I->grabPageSource()` and `$I->_getResponseContent()` to work though there are these exact functions.

```
public function checkCall(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnRoute('mx/ed',['model' => 'State']);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIsSuccessful();
    $html = $I->grabPageSource();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Codeception saves page source of last request for all failed tests in `tests/_output` directory by itself, there is nothing for you to do.

Failed assertion throws exception so your code after `$I->seeResponseCodeIsSuccessful` is not executed.

If you want to implement some custom error handling in specific test, you can wrap assertions in try-catch block and grabPageSource inside catch.

```
public function checkCall(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnRoute('mx/ed',['model' => 'State']);
    try{
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIsSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $html = $I->grabPageSource();
        //do your error handling here
        throw $e; //rethrow exception to make test fail
    }
}
```

If you want to implement custom error handling for all tests, add [_failed method](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Hooks) to `Helper\Functional` class in `tests/_support/Helper` directory.

```
public function _failed(\Codeception\TestInterface $test, $fail)
{
    $testName = $test->getMetadata()->getName();
    $pageSource = $this->getModule('Yii2')->getPageSource();
    //do your error handling here
}
```

Comment: That is good but I still need the html within my unit. Any way to get it?